# How to group all values in a For loop and print grouped value to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with excel vba programing, I need to group values in a For loop and print grouped list to other sheet, here is my code

```
Dim grafikas As Worksheet
Dim akcijos As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim prekeskodas As Long
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim laikas As Date
Dim ats As String


Set grafikas = Sheets("GRAFIKAS")
Set akcijos = Sheets("AKCIJOS")

lastrow = akcijos.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
paskeil = grafikas.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

prekeskodas = grafikas.Range("B48").Value

laikas = grafikas.Range("F1").Value
laikas2 = grafikas.Range("CK1").Value

For x = 2 To lastrow
    If akcijos.Cells(x, 4) = prekeskodas And akcijos.Cells(x, 8) >= laikas Then
       ats = akcijos.Cells(x, 3)
       Sheets("grafikas").Range("C7") = ats
       Debug.Print akcijos.Cells(x, 3)
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: Hi, Went through your code and tried at my end, and is performing without any error. What is exactly the requirement. not able to understand.

Comment: Hi, I just need to group all values in "grafikas" sheet  that are got from for cicle for.

Comment: You will get better and more answers if you are more specific and explain in detail what you want to accomplish. Your explanation "group all values in "grafikas" sheet that are got from for cicle for" does not make much sense.